# How to extract integers from a QByteArray in Qt using toInt?

Tags: c++, qt

I am a beginner with C++ and Qt.  The data sent is a string of ASCII characters ex:"jdlsfjffjf: XX" where I would like to extract the number XX. I know I should possibly use indexof to point to it but not sure how. Any direction? Here's the server side code that receives, displays and writes. I get the correct numbers in the application but gibberish characters in the file I'm writing to.

```
void Receiver::processPendingDatagrams()
    {
        while (udpSocket->hasPendingDatagrams()) {
            QByteArray datagram; //array of bytes
            datagram.resize(udpSocket->pendingDatagramSize()); //size it depending on sent data
            udpSocket->readDatagram(datagram.data(), datagram.size()); //read all
            statusLabel->setText(tr("%1 C").arg(datagram.data()));


            //writing stream to file
            bool ok;
            QFile file("file.dat");
            file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
            QDataStream out(&file);   
            out << datagram.toInt(&ok, 10 );        
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int num = datagram.right(datagram.size() - datagram.indexOf(':') - 1).toInt();
```

Comment: I debugged and getting the integer in num. However, when writing to file, I am getting three blank spaces and then the ASCII equivilant of the last sent integer. I want a list of all the integers on a new line. How I'm writing is:                                                                                                 
                                                                                                   out << temp_received;

Comment: temp_received is just the name I gave num in your example.

Comment: you should convert the integer to int then write: QString numStr = QString("%1").arg(num); and on writing: out << numStr;

Comment: Worked. Thank you. I'm sorry I can't +1 you but I hope someone else does.